# Titanium delete TableViewRow, model-view binding should automatically reflect tableview

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

This is how I delete a tableviewrow on a longclick event of a tableview (android)
    $.tableview.deleteRow(e.index); , but this just removes the row.
How do I also remove the data on my tableviewrow which will in turn remove it from collection via model id, and model-view binding should automatically reflect this in tableview.Any Ideas?Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to delete the model object from the collection which will then trigger the appropriate events to update the table.

So in your longpress event

```
$.tableview.deleteRow(e.index);
collection.models[e.index].destroy() // should delete model, use index to get model
                                     // from the collection

collection.fetch();                  // should force table to update
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, but i dont know why im getting an error at this line: collection.models[e.index].destroy() , & a message says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined".