# Titanium Alloy get all label text value from xml

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to console log all label text value displayed from my xml, And this is how I was doing to log the label Ti.API.info($.label.getText()); , but this code doesn't seem to work since this only works for only a single value from a variable. How I'm going to do this? Sorry,Just so noob enough. Thanks!

```
<TableView id="table" dataCollection="person">
   <TableViewRow id="row">
     <Label id="label" text="{name}"></Label>
   </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

Comment: people in this community are helpful, but it is good practice to respond and/or accept answers before asking more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419483/titanium-delete-tableviewrow-model-view-binding-should-automatically-reflect-ta/17425253#comment25332406_17425253

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the Appcelerator documentation http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding

**dataTransform**: specifies an optional callback to use to format model attributes. The passed argument is a model and the return value is a modified model as a JSON object.

```
<TableView id="table" dataCollection="person" dataTransform="dumpText" >
   <TableViewRow id="row">
     <Label id="label" text="{name}"></Label>
   </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

So we can use this method to dump whatever is being added to the list

```
function dumpText(model) {
    // model to a JSON object
    var o = model.toJSON();
    Ti.API.info(o.name);
    return o;
}
```

Comment: this works,Thank you so much Aaron for all your courage at helping me. Keep it up :)